# Where can find the get_video_info api parameter infomation?

Tags: api, youtube

Youtube API - https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id={videoId} has a lot of parameters.

But I google and find no place to get all the paramters and which value can be taked.

Where can find an page including which parameter can be used.

Sorry for my poor English, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The url (slug) itself has been discontinued

Brendan O.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).